# php cookie does not work at the first time reading

Tags: php, cookies

I am a beginner for PHP and studying to use   cookie for login.  Would any body please check my code to see what is my problem, or let me how to fix this problem.

When I open the page at the first time, the cookie will not work.  It will work when I repeated to open that link. However, I  still could not make it work after I use function include and header One of codes is :

One code  cookie.php is :

```
<?php
setcookie("cookiename",$_REQUEST['name']);
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookiename'])){
$cookieSet = ' The Cookie is ' .  $_COOKIE['cookiename'];
} else {
$cookieset = ' No Cookie has been set';
}
setcookie("cookiepwd",$_REQUEST['pwd']);
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

When I run this code first time,  it will does not show any thing. I can see cookie data at second time. From some website it is said that cookie would not be read at the same page.

So I moved print_r($_COOKIE)  to second php file  as well as added function include() or  header()  to above file, but both neither works.

Cookie2.php:

```
<?php
setcookie("cookiename",$_REQUEST['name']);
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookiename'])){
$cookieSet = ' The Cookie is ' .  $_COOKIE['cookiename'];
} else {
$cookieset = ' No Cookie has been set';
}
setcookie("cookiepwd",$_REQUEST['pwd']);
include(‘printcookie.php’);
//or header("Location: printcookie.php")
?>
```

printcookie.php:

```
<?php
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

Thank you very much for answering in advance!

Michelle

Comment: PHP's superglobals are set when the script starts up and then never touched again by PHP. anything you do within the script that would change a superglobal will only be visible the NEXT time the script runs.

Comment: @Marc B: "anything you do within the script that would change a superglobal will only be visible the NEXT time the script runs" --- it is too vague

Answer (score 3):

`setcookie` only sets up the header, that is being sent to the client. It doesn't change the `$_COOKIE` superglobal.

In other hand - `$_COOKIE` is filled up with the cookies sent **from the client**

So at first step - you set the cookie with `setcookie` and have nothing in `$_COOKIE` because client hasn't sent it yet, and will only on the next request.

And there is no way of doing what you want, rather than modifying `$_COOKIE` manually

PS: it is a bad idea to put user's password in the cookie

Answer (score 2):

Give zerkms the answer, but I just want to reiterate:

1. Cookies are not bad for storing bits of info like the user's theme preferences or preferred start page, etc.  They get their bad rep from being used for identity and authentication handling. There are cookies out there that basically have "isAdmin=0" in order to control user access. It is *very* easy to change that to `isAdmin=1` and have a field day.  Since you are new to PHP, take the time to learn about sessions now while it's all new to you.
2. When you set a cookie using `setcookie`, you are sending an HTTP header to the browser with the cookie info.  The browser will then pass back that cookie in any future requests to the server.  The `$_COOKIE` global variable holds the cookie info passed in from the browser to the server.
3. Since you are using `$_REQUEST` to get the cookie name, you don't need to check the cookie (otherwise you wouldn't have the data to set it right?). So consider going this route:

   ```
   if(!isset($_COOKIE['cookiename'])) {
         $name = $_POST['name']);
         setcookie("cookiename",$name);
    } else {
       $name = $_COOKIE['cookiename']);
    }

   echo "Welcome back $name!";
   ```

This will also help out if they clear cookies, etc.

But really, the safer route is:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name']);
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['pwd'])){
    $_SESSION['pwd'] = $_POST['pwd']);
}

$name =  $_SESSION['name'];
$pwd = $_SESSION['pwd'];
```

And even this would be frowned upon for serious web security, where you should simply check the password against a stored hash and then delete it, using other global variables to confirm session integrity. But there's now a whole StackExchange for that.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could use location() after checking the cookie to have access to the stored data.

But be aware that location() fails, if anything (including breaks and blanks in your script) already sent to the browser.